# How can I use AJAX to call a Wordpress function?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm a newbie to Wordpress and PHP and I'm trying to load more posts on a button click (i tried infinite scroll, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for). I echoed the admin-ajax URL into my HTML and I'm getting it from an input and sending along some data via Jquery Post function. The request is fine, i get no errors, but it just returns 0 and i don't know if it's reaching my desired function.

So, how can i:

- Be sure it is reaching my function?
- How to return some html data from my function?

Here's my JS code:

```
$('.loadMore-button-link').click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var adminUrl = $('#inputAdminAjax').val();

    var data = {
        posts_per_page: 3,
        post_offset: postOffset,
        action: 'getPosts'
    };
    $.post(adminUrl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here's my PHP code (in my functions.php file):

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getPosts", "getPosts");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getPosts", "getPosts");

function getPosts() {
    global $wpdb;

    var postOffset = $_POST['postOffset'];

    query_posts(array(
        'category_name' => 'portfolio',
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST['posts_per_page'])
    );

    return 1; //this was a test
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the action parameter yet? `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="getPosts">`

Comment: I don't get it. Why should I use a input hidden?

Comment: Just add it, it defines the last part of `wp_ajax_` which in your case is `wp_ajax_getPosts`.

Comment: I'm not using a form, just a button click. I've already defined the active in the data I'm sending via ajax with the correct value.

Comment: It's action not active.

Comment: Thanks for your help man. I could get it to work changing the request from POST to GET, which makes much more sense.